# git fatal: when trying git rm --cached

Tags: eclipse, git

Hi When trying to switch between branch, I have a error:

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
        Project/.project
Please move or remove them before you can switch branches.
```

but when I try to use

```
git rm --cached  Project/.project
```

I get a error:

```
fatal: pathspec 'Project/.project' did not match any files
```

Please suggest a work a round, Any way some of the files might be moved is some of the branches and the added a gain, and please explaine the two errors.
Thanks

Comment: What's the output of `ls -l Project/.project`?

Comment: Just remove Projects/.project directory if you don't care about changes within it.

Comment: -rw-rw-r-- 1 me me 815 Dec  4 13:11 Project/.project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a workaround, either remove `Projects/.project` or save it somewhere outside your repository if you need to keep it.

What is happening is your current work tree on your current branch has this file, but you are not tracking it (and maybe it's `.gitignored` on top of that). However in the branch you want to checkout, someone has at some point in the past `git add`ed and committed that file. Since your current copy is not tracked by `git`, `git` refuses to overwrite it with the tracked copy, and also refuses to `git rm --cached` it, because it doesn't know anything about it. This is in general a good thing. However, you might need to evaluate whether this file needs to be tracked, and if not, perhaps it needs to be purged from that other branch...

Comment: thanks for the helpful answer,  the scenario is exactly as you have described.I removed the problematic files and it works, My only consurn now is what happens when I need to merge this branch, where the file is not tracked(the master) with the branch where the file is tracked(the feature branch). At the end I need to have the file tracked.